# Show 2 Windows at Same time in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qwidget, qmainwindow

How can i show two windows at same time ?  Well i have a mainwindow ,then when i press a button i load a plugin which creates and return a qwidget, and set it as central widget `setCentralWidget()` ,but my app crashes .If i'm not wrong this anyway will show just one window at same time .

Code from plugin :

```
QWidget* PlPlugin::initPltter() {

    plotter = new QWidget();
    plotter->resize(200,300);
    plotter->setWindowTitle("mypl");
    plotter->show();

    return plotter;
}
```

In my app i'm doing :

```
setCentralWidget(plotter->initPlotter());
```

Comment: what does the error show? with qt widgets it is all about parents, you should be able to pass parent window to show second plot

Comment: Do you want to show two _windows_, or two _widgets_ inside the main window? In the first case, don't set the plotter widget as central widget. In the second case, you should add a container widget with a layout (or QSplitter, QDockwidget etc.) add the plotter as child to the layout. In that case, don't call show() on the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try not resizing or showing it. Its unnecessary if its going to become a central widget of the mainwindow.

Also, from your example there is nothing suggesting that you are trying to show two windows. What you are doing is creating another widget and setting it as a child of the main window. Do one or the other: Create the widget and show it directly, or create it and parent it under another.

Answer (score 0):

Your MainWindow child shown in main.cpp, for second widget do this:

```
QWidget* PlPlugin::initPltter() {

  plotter = new QWidget();
  plotter->resize(200,300);
  plotter->setWindowTitle("mypl");
  plotter->show();

  return plotter;
}
```

And **don't** do this

```
setCentralWidget(plotter->initPlotter());
```

It allow you to get MainWindow and widget in separate 'window'